# EXCEL replace values in sheet with value from another column

Tags: excel, formula

Im trying to replace values spread across a section of a worksheet with corresponding values in a column across from them.

For example...

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
-----------------------------
D1                          A
    D2                      B
             D3             C
                  D4        D
```

Is there a way I can have all the D+number values replaced with their value from the last column (A,B,C,D)?

Googled but couldn't find much except find and replace but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Not with a formula.  this would require vba code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by the very simple macro:

```
Sub FindNReplace()
  Dim cc As Range
  For Each cc In Selection.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(cc) Then cc = Cells(cc.Row, "H")
  Next
End Sub
```

It replaces the value of any non-empty cell in the selection by the value in same row of the column "H".